# Archiving succesive beta versions : how to save harddisk space?

Tags: diff, patch, archive, beta, rar

I archive successive versions of an in-progress work :

MySoftware-v1.01beta.rar  [2 GB]

MySoftware-v1.02beta.rar  [2 GB]

MySoftware-v1.03beta.rar  [2 GB]

MySoftware-v1.04beta.rar  [2 GB]

etc.

*Lots of files are modified, so it's not possible to backup only modified files : most of the files are modified each time.*

**How can do a .rar file that only saves the "difference"**   (should I use something like "patch" or "diff"  ? -> I never used them).   There are lots of "difference" tool, okay, but the result file won't be a .rar, it will only be a "difference file" : so each time I would like to re-open such an archive, I'll have to "de-diff" it and only THEN I will have a .rar again.

I'm on Windows, and if possible, I'd like to use winrar or command-line tool (it would be great if no third party software is needed).

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You say 90% of your product is .wav files.  Since diff on two wav files that are different is likely to produce huge differences, this is not likely to save you any space.  Nor are .wav files *really* compressible, so zip or rar likely doesn't help much, either.

However, if, like most of us programmers, you derive your next version of the product from the previous one, by mostly retaining files unchanged (whether that be source or be .wav files), then what you really want to do is simply store, for each version, the files that changed.   This is called "de-duplication" in the backup/compression world.

You can organize a complicated scheme your self to do this. (e.g., your self-suggested "do this with winrar").  But if you use a decent "source control system" (SVN or GIT would be fine), this will happen automatically as you checkin changed (and don't re-checkin unchanged) files.   These tools work by keeping track of "differences" between versions; you can tell the tools to track text ("diff") style differences, or simply store the entire thing.

Also, since your individual versions occupy 2GB, I'd go waste $100 on a 2 or 4 terabyte (external) drive. That should last you in worst case through some 1000 iterations. (SVN/GIT will likely extended this a lot further).

Comment: Yeah, it's 2012, not 1997. Hard disk space is cheap and 2gig is nothing. More disks and keep doing your winrar method if it works for you (but a real source control system will save your sanity and hours of your life one day, guaranteed, just like a real automated backup system has saved mine many times)

Answer (score 1):

You should really be using a [source control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_control). A popular one is called '[git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29)'. There are many others, each with their own strengths and weaknesses and the debate about which is 'best' is long and tedious.

Source control systems take care of storing and managing revisions of your files. The actual methods vary, but as a programmer who uses version control you 'check in' files for storage and version control, 'tag' them with revision numbers and then 'check out' files for modifying.

If you've ever downloaded source off the Internet using 'svn' or 'cvs', that's the type of thing I mean.

The source control system usually uses some sort of difference system to only store differences between modified files. Its purpose is to save you from having to even think about copying and backing up files - all you have to do is ensure your 'repository' is backed up correctly.

Also, as an added advantage you can make changes to source files and always have backups in case your changes need reverting. So suppose you want to try out a new file handling system you can use the source control system to create a testing (or whatever you want to call it) 'branch' and do all your changes in there without damaging a working copy of your software. If the changes are good you can then 'merge' the changes into the non testing branch of your repository.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

In fact 90% of the project is wav files and some other types of multimedia files. So it's not really sourcecode...

Don't you think it's possible just with rar / winrar features?

Thanks a lot!